# How to convert to byte array in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a form field of type password. I want the entered password to be converted to byte array. How can I do it using react?The format of form field is as below.

```
<Form.Input
                required
                label="Account Password"
                type="password"
                value={this.state.password}
                onChange={this.handleChangePassword}
                />
```

Comment: check this https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/3589

Answer (score 0):

Password string must be in utf16 encoding it can converted to utf8 encoding and then to byte array.

```
let utf8 = unescape(encodeURIComponent(this.state.password));  
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < utf8.length; i++) {
    arr.push(utf8.charCodeAt(i));
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If it had helped can you please mark the answer as correct :)

Comment: I have marked it as useful.Since my reputation is not more than 15 it won't be displayed publicly but the votes will be considered.

Comment: You can use String.fromCharCode() to reverse the charCodeAt and use decodeURIComponent decode it back to state.

Comment: I want to store byte array format of password in this.state.password.